Making an interactive graph on R using ggplotly/Plotly
I am struggling to get my interactive graph to look how I want it to using both ggplotly and Plotly. I've tried various ways, and am stuck (and in a time crunch). When using ggplotly, I expected my legends to be preserved from the static version to interactive, but one of them disappears. Someone suggested Plotly as a workaround, but I can't seem to get that to work either. Can someone please help me figure this out?
Here is my detailed post on biostars about the problems I am experiencing: https://www.biostars.org/p/9594858/
Thanks!

Hi Jennifer Herrera, welcome to SO. Please do not cross-post if your question is still 'fresh' on another site. Give people a chance to respond before seeking help elsewhere. Also, this site expects a self-contained minimal, reproducible example that doesn't rely solely on an external link. This link has some really useful guidance regarding how to create an MRE, and how to share example data in particular. Thanks.

As mentioned by L Tyrone, could you please share some code you have tried and reproducible code using dput?
